Compare items in two SharePoint lists,if they are equal- get another field from one of the list - Power Automate
I have two lists.
List A and List B
List A has below column - Called Column1(Calculated)
Calculated Column - =INT(IF(AND(Value<20000,[Request Type]="Note"),1,IF(AND(Value<50000,[Request Type]="Note"),2,0)))
List B has column - Column2(Number)
I want a power automate flow where it gives me FIELD1 from List B IF Column1 and Column 2 are same.
Field1 is person/group.
I have been struggling for so long. I dont know what is wrong here.
I tried with Get function

Using Select, Join, and Filter array steps along with int(), union(), and string() functions, items from one list (List B) can be filtered based on values of a field in another list (List A).

See the screenshots and expressions of a Power Automate that I've tested with.


Steps described below

Get the items from List A and Select values of [Column1].


Remove Duplicates and create a comma separated string of the array (output  from step 1). Use union() function and Join step


Get Items of List B and User Filter array step to extract the desired filter items



See the expression for the screenshot above
 [output]
 body('Join_|_create_a_comma_separated_string')

 contains

 string(item()?['Column2'])



Print out required fields' values from the filtered items. In this case, FILED1/Email and [Column2]


